# 2D Drawing On a Virtual 3D Plane in RealityKit

Tags: ios, swift, realitykit

I'm trying to draw a 2D stroke using my finger on a 3D plane I generated and added to the scene:

```
let material = SimpleMaterial.init(color: .white,
                                   roughness: 1,
                                   isMetallic: false)
let plane = MeshResource.generatePlane(width: 1.5,
                                       height: 1.0)
                                       
let planeEntity = ModelEntity(mesh: plane,
                              materials: [material])
planeEntity.collision = CollisionComponent(shapes: [.generateBox(size: [1.5, 1.0, 0.05])],
                                           mode: .trigger,
                                           filter: .sensor)
planeEntity.name = "TargetPlane"
planeEntity.position = SIMD3(x: 0.0,
                             y: 0.0,
                             z: 0.0)
self.scene.addChild(planeEntity)
```

I'm getting the points along the finger path using a pan recognizer on my `ARView`:

```
@objc func handlePan(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let touchInView = sender.location(in: self.arView)
        guard let hitEntity = self.arView.entity(at: touchInView) else { return } // No entity was hit.
        
        if hitEntity.name == "TargetPlane" {
                if sender.state == .began || sender.state == .changed {
                        let result = self.arView.hitTest(touchInView)
                        guard let collision = result.first else { return }
                        
                        // Convert from world space to local plane space.
                        let position = planeEntity.convert(position: collision.position,
                                                           from: nil)
                }
        }
}
```

At this point I have points in the plane's local co-ordinates. I thought of using a `UIBezierPath` and drawing it onto a `CAShapeLayer` then rendering a `UIImage` out of it and using that as a texture on the plane.

The problem is I have no idea how to map the 3D points to 2D pixel co-ordinates on the plane.

I'm aware of the [`project(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/arview/project(_:)) method but that maps points to the whole viewport of the device. I need to map the points to the surface of the virtual plane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out using the pinhole camera model.

```
if sender.state == .began || sender.state == .changed {
        let result = self.arView.hitTest(touchInView)
        guard let collision = result.first else { return }
        
        // Convert the point from world space to the plane's local space.
        let position = planeEntity.convert(position: collision.position,
                                           from: nil)
        
        // Get the focal length.
        let intrinsics = (self.arView.session.currentFrame?.camera.intrinsics)!
        let f_x = intrinsics.columns.0.x
        let f_y = intrinsics.columns.1.y

        // Co-ordinates of the principal point.
        let c_x = intrinsics.columns.2.x
        let c_y = intrinsics.columns.2.y

        // (x, y, z) of the 3D point on the plane.
        let x = position.x
        let y = position.y
        let z = collision.distance
        
        // Map to 2D (u, v) co-ordinates.
        let u = (x / z) * f_x + c_x
        let v = (y / z) * f_y + c_y
        
        // Shift the origin to the top left corner for Core Graphics.
        let u_max = (planeEntity.model!.mesh.bounds.max.x / z) * f_x + c_x
        let v_max = (planeEntity.model!.mesh.bounds.max.y / z) * f_y + c_y
        let u_mapped = max(u, 0) // Clamp to avoid negative values.
        let v_mapped = max(v_max - v, 0)
        
        // Add this point to the UIBezierPath.
        let mappedPoint = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(u_mapped),
                                  y: CGFloat(v_mapped))

        // Use this as the size of the image renderer.
        let canvasSize = CGSize(width: u_max,
                                height: v_max)
}
```